# Binding issue in custom Xamarin.Forms control

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms

I have a strange problem with bindings on a custom control. I created a custom toolbar:

```
public partial class TopToolbar
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BackCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BackCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(TopToolbar), propertyChanged: BackCommandChanged);

    public ICommand BackCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand) GetValue(BackCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(BackCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public TopToolbar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // for debug purposes only
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        Debug.WriteLine(BindingContext);
    }

    // for debug purposes only
    private static void BackCommandChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"old: {oldvalue}, new: {newvalue}");
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Core.Controls.TopToolbar"
             x:Name="TopToolbarView"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference TopToolbarView}"
             Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                <Image Source="{StaticResource Image.Toolbar.LeftArrow}">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

I use it on a page in this way:

```
<pages:ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}"
                     Spacing="0"
                     Padding="0">
            <controls:TopToolbar Title="Master Data" BackCommand="{Binding MyBackCommand}" />
```

`BindingContext` of the page is a view model:

```
public class MyCustomersPageModel
{
    public RelayCommand MyBackCommand { get; set; }

    public MyCustomersPageModel()
    {
        MyBackCommand = // command creation;
    }
}
```

From the debugging I know that `BindingContext` of a control is set (`OnBindingContextChanged` called) properly to itself (`TopToolbar` object) twice - first time when there's no child views and second time after they are added. I've checked that `BindingContext` is correctly propagated in all child controls.

Unfortunately the `BackCommand` is not bind at all. The setter of the `TopToolbar.BackCommand` is not called even once.

Interestingly when I replace setting the `BindingContext` on a control to setting the `Souce` directly in bindings everything works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Core.Controls.TopToolbar"
             x:Name="TopToolbarView"
             Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                <Image Source="{StaticResource Image.Toolbar.LeftArrow}">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TopToolbarView}, Path=BackCommand}" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Any clue what I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working as expected. I would recommend using `Source`.

In first case, when you set `BindingContext` on `TopToolbar` to itself, then I would imagine this would be the sequence of events:

1. Custom control is constructed, `BindingContext` is assigned to self through reference.
2. Page instance is created, control is added to it.
3. When page's `BindingContext` is set, through power of property inheritance, all it's child controls' `BindingContext` is updated.
4. At this point your custom control's `BindingContext` is still referencing itself [as value-propagation doesn't override manually set context](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs#L95).
5. Therefore, binding `<controls:TopToolbar BackCommand="{Binding MyBackCommand}"` fails, as this binding will try to look for `MyBackCommand` on it's binding-context which is `TopToolbar`.

But, in second case, when you specify binding `Source` as `TopToolbar` on `Tapped` command, then this should be the sequence of events:

1. Custom control is constructed, `BindingContext` is null.
2. Page instance is created, control is added to it.
3. When page's `BindingContext` is set, through power of property inheritance, all it's child controls' `BindingContext` is updated, including your custom control.
4. At this point your custom control's `BindingContext` is now referencing `MyCustomersPageModel`. So binding in `<controls:TopToolbar BackCommand="{Binding MyBackCommand}"` is appropriately set.
5. Now the `Tapped` binding doesn't care about `BindingContext` as it's source is explicitly specified, which is parent control `TopToolbar` - whose `BackCommand` in turn is bound to the view model's command. Hence, the view-model command is now bound to gesture-recognizer's `Tapped` command. And it works!

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!

Comment: Great! I hope the answer was helpful.